# How can I tell if another object method has been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have my object of functions and I'd like to test if 1 method has called the other one but spy seems to fail because the test says it's due to that the function haven't been called at all. I'm adding the code.
**index.js**

```js
const funcObject = () => {
    const firstFunc = () => {
        console.log('first func!')
    };
    const secondFunc = () => {
        firstFunc();
        console.log('second func!');
    }
    return {
        firstFunc,
        secondFunc
    };
};

module.exports = funcObject;
```

**index.test.js**

```js
const funcObject = require('./index');

describe('second func tests', () => {
    it('should call first func', () => {
        const funcObjectOutput = funcObject();
        const firstFuncSpy = jest.spyOn(funcObjectOutput, 'firstFunc');
        funcObjectOutput.secondFunc();

        expect(firstFuncSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "jest-mock",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't, unless you refer them as methods on `this` or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the `firstFunc()` called inside the `secondFunc()` will be original function, NOT spied version.

In order to spy or mock the `firstFunc()` function, you need to retrieve the reference of it. In this way, when the `secondFunc()` function is called, the spied `firstFunc()` function will be called. For more info, see this [How to mock specific module function?](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-214939935)

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const funcObject = () => {
  const obj = {};
  const firstFunc = () => {
    console.log('first func!');
  };
  const secondFunc = () => {
    obj.firstFunc();
    console.log('second func!');
  };

  obj.firstFunc = firstFunc;
  obj.secondFunc = secondFunc;
  return obj;
};

module.exports = funcObject;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const funcObject = require('./index');

describe('second func tests', () => {
  it('should call first func', () => {
    const funcObjectOutput = funcObject();
    const firstFuncSpy = jest.spyOn(funcObjectOutput, 'firstFunc');
    funcObjectOutput.secondFunc();

    expect(firstFuncSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66657164/index.test.js
  second func tests
    ✓ should call first func (19 ms)

  console.log
    first func!

      at Object.firstFunc (examples/66657164/index.js:4:13)

  console.log
    second func!

      at Object.secondFunc (examples/66657164/index.js:8:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.69 s
```

Answer (score 1):

`jest.spyOn(funcObjectOutput, 'firstFunc')` replaces `funcObjectOutput['firstFunc']` with a mock function. So `firstFuncSpy` is the mock one rather than original. And `expect(firstFuncSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` checks whether the mock function has been called. But `secondFunc` calls the original `firstFunc`.

See code of `jest.spyOn`.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/dd1309652334ab14544cf3ecb177faae68059832/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L951